# Unable to post a question due to formatting issues

Tags: support, code-formatting, formatting

**Why am I getting an error as follows for the post content (after the dashed line)**

*"Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon."*

**This is my post. I think the issue is coming from the latex code.**

---

I am trying to solve a simple PDE in the cylindrical coordinates:

$$ \frac{\partial c}{\partial t} = D \bigg(\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial c}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial c^2}{\partial r^2}\bigg)$$

The initial and boundary conditions are as follows:

$$ c[t=0,r] = {0,\hspace{2mm} r<=r_0 ;\hspace{2mm} C_b, \hspace{2mm} r> r_0}$$
$$ c[t,r=\infty] = C_b$$
$$ \frac{\partial c}{\partial r}[t,r=0] = 0$$

I wrote the following code first in Mathematica:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];

ClearAll[DiffCoeff, Cb, c1, r, t, pde, radialDerivative, \
secondRadialDerivative, boundaryConditions, initialCondition, sol, \
AvgConcentration, r0, tmax, inf]

DiffCoeff = 1; Cb = 1; r0 = 1; tmax = 10; inf = 100;

(*Define the PDE with NeumannValue for the flux condition*)
radialDerivative = 1/r*Derivative[1, 0][c1][t, r];
secondRadialDerivative = Derivative[2, 0][c1][t, r];
pde = Derivative[0, 1][c1][t, r] - 
    DiffCoeff*(radialDerivative + secondRadialDerivative) == 
   NeumannValue[0, r == 0];

(*Boundary Condition using DirichletCondition*)
boundaryConditions = 
 DirichletCondition[c1[t, r] == Cb, 
  r == inf];
(*Initial condition:c1(0,r)=0 for r<=r0 and Cb r>r0*)
initialCondition = c1[0, r] == If[r <= r0, 0, Cb];
(*Solve the PDE*)
sol = NDSolveValue[{pde, boundaryConditions, initialCondition}, 
  c1, {t, 0, tmax}, {r, 0, inf}]
```

This solves with a warning:

```
NDSolveValue::femcscd: The PDE is convection dominated and the result may not be stable. Adding artificial diffusion may help.
```

Now, I was trying to solve the warning by smoothening the mesh with the following modification to the code:

```
(*Create a custom mesh*)
mesh = ToGradedMesh[{{Line[{{0}, {2*r0}}], <|
     "MaximalDistance" -> 0.1|>}, {Line[{{2*r0}, {inf}}]}}]
MeshRegion[mesh]

sol = NDSolveValue[{pde, boundaryConditions, initialCondition}, 
  c1, {t, 0, tmax}, {r} \[Element] mesh]
```

And this gives an error which I would like to solve:

```
NDSolveValue::femnotime: The differential equation cannot be solved as a time dependent equation as specified, most likely because the initial conditions given at (t==0.`) are not sufficient to define an initial value problem. As a consequence the differential equation will be solved as a time independent equation.
```

and

```
NDSolveValue::fememrc: The ranges {{0.,300.},ElementMesh[{{0.},{0.1},{0.2},{0.3},{0.4},{0.5},{0.6},{0.7},{0.8},{0.9},<<431>>},{LineElement[{{1,2,222},{2,3,223},{3,4,224},{4,5,225},{5,6,226},{6,7,227},{7,8,228},{8,9,229},{9,10,230},{10,11,231},<<210>>},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,<<210>>}]},{PointElement[{{1},{221}}]},{PointElement[{{1},{221}}]}]} cannot be combined to a region. Please specify a combined region.
```

Now I am open to refining the original mesh in the NDSolve Function itself, maybe using the MaxCellMeasure function. But I want the mesh to be non-uniform. Will MaxCellMeasure allow me to do that?

Comment: Same issue as [this one](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2736/5). Unfortunately we don't really know why the filter is rejecting your question, but I suspect it is due to the LaTeX code. I suggest trying what Domen suggested in the other post, i.e. remove the latex blocks and push the rest of the question through and you/someone else can try editing it back in after the question is live.

Comment: Ok, I will try that now. I am new to community, but will be happy to help if needed to to rectify this issue.

Comment: @rm-rf this worked, thanks for commenting and helping me out.

Comment: No problem, and welcome to the community! :)