# Cannot submit question with display math

Tags: bug

As per title, it seems that it is not possible to submit a question in which display math (i.e. $$ ... $$) is present.

If you try to ask this question

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum


$$
e^{i\tau} = 1
$$
```

you will get the error

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as
> code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button
> or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?]
> toolbar icon.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem as explained. Care to share more details?

Comment: Which details would you be interested in? To reproduce it, for me at least, I simply go to the main site -> Ask question -> Input question as above -> Get the error above

Comment: Same issue as [here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2750/5). Please submit your question initially without the LaTeX math and then edit it to add it back in. That seems to work.

Comment: I tried that but didn't work!